# Blazor NavigationManager NavigateTo throwing Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: c#, url, blazor, blazor-server-side

While using `NavigationManager` in blazor

```
[Inject]
private NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }
```

And calling `NavigationManager.NavigateTo`, some urls works, others don't, but if I pass directly in the browser url bar the url that doesn't work, it works.

Example.

If I call `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Basics/Soil/Edit/1")` it will work in the code and also if I change the url in the browser url bar.

But

If I call `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Basics/Soil/List")`, it will give me the following error

> Error: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
> at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)

But if I pass that url directly in the browser, it will work and give no error because I do have a component with `@page "/Basics/Soil/List"`.

I can't understand why it doesn't work with some urls, even when I have a matching component.

## Edit:

I have found where the problem happens, but still not sure why.

[Here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3148acfb105a16aa6c535d00eb0e50ec03992f3f/src/Components/Server/src/Circuits/RemoteNavigationManager.cs#L74) it try to create an absolute uri, which will just [return a new Uri](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Components/src/NavigationManager.cs#L153) and it's on this method where the function [Uri.CreateThis](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/URI.cs#L459) comes from, but then, looks like it just become a mess and I can't understand why and where it throws the error.

Comment: Maybe you can step into the Blazor source code to see the actual value of the `uri` parameter it complains about?

Comment: @UweKeim, I can't. The only thing I can see is the code from metadata. I can't debug it

Comment: @UweKeim I have found where the problem in the source code comes from, but still don't understand